# Image is not displayed in python

Tags: image, python-2.7, tkinter

I am writing the following code for display image in my window but image is not displayed. Only blank window appearing.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from Tkinter import *
import matplotlib, sys
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib import pylab as plt
root=Tk()
fr=Frame(root)
fr.pack()
image = mpimg.imread("C:\Users\Public\Pictures\SamplePictures\Koala.jpg")
f = Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100)  
im=plt.imshow(image)
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, fr)
canvas.show()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=1)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Does this actual code work without giving any errors?

Comment: Actual code is not giving any error but image did not shown in the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Above question have solution to display image in canvas. we need to replace 
f= Figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100) into f=plt.figure(figsize=(5,5), dpi=100) this line